# Inner dict ordering by key

Tags: python, mongodb

First of all, my structure is following:

```
Collection=[
{
    'somekey':'',
    "anotherkey":'',
    'embedded':[
        {
            'value':'',
            'ordering':1
        },
        {
            'value':'',
            'ordering':3
        },
        {
            'value':'',
            'ordering':2
        },
    ]
},
{...},
{...},
]
```

I always receive only one document from this collection by key, so all parts of question use this in mind.

1) Can i receive this document, while 'embedded' list will be ordered by inner ordering using pure mongo.db shell?

2) If answer is yes can same be done with mongoalchemy?

3) Meanwhile, i did not find answer for first question, so I pre-sort by ordering in python before insertion into mongodb. When i retreive document it still in right order.
But can i rely on it, will it be for sure in same order when database will grow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items in an embedded array are stored in the order you added them. As you are sorting to the order you want before inserting then it is okay, and you can rely on this to remain constant. If you want a different order you'd need to bring the whole array back to the client and sort it there.